# How do I get a list of items with Ebean using complex query

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I have 3 models, model for town, that has a field for regionId, model for region, that has a field for stateId.

model for town:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "town")
public class Town extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "town_id_seq")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "region_id")
    private Integer regionId;
    ...
```

model for region:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "region")
public class Region extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "region_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "state_id", nullable = false)
    private Long stateId;
    ...
```

model for state:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "state")
public class State extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "state_id_seq")
    private Integer id;
    ...
```

I need to get list of towns in specific state. In SQL I would do something like this:

```
select * from town join region on town.region_id = region.id 
where region.state_id=15666
```

I did fetch of two tables

```
public static List<Town> findAllInState(Integer stateId) {
    return Ebean.find(Town.class).fetch("region").findList();
}
```

but when I try to add `.where().eq("region.stateId", stateId)` it shows `BeanList size[0] hasMoreRows[false] list[]`

How can I get it using Ebean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding `@ManyToOne` relations in `Town` and `Region` instead of `@Column` fields.

So in `Town` class remove:

```
@Column(name = "state_id", nullable = false)
private Long stateId;
```

and add:

```
@ManyToOne
public Region region;
```

In `Region` class remove:

```
@Column(name = "state_id", nullable = false)
private Long stateId;
```

and add:

```
@ManyToOne
public State state;
```

Then you will be able to find towns of given state with following query:

```
Ebean.find(Town.class).where().eq("region.state.id", stateId).findList();
```